# Error during display of session value,Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am taking the the GridView row count in session and then displaying the session value to a label.

I am displaying it in the master page but it is not executing its throwing this error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Can anyone help me?

My Code:

```
Session["Count"] = GridView1.Rows.Count.ToString();
Label1.Text = Session["Count"].ToString();
```

Comment: Why don't directly assign count.ToString to label.text? Why use session?

Comment: This is quite clear that your count Session did not created, where that session created in which event?, provide more code.

Comment: I created this in shopping cart page and set the count of gridview row in session and trying to display it to the master page.If i m missing something then plz explain